# Getting an error "ORA-00093: pga_aggregate_target must be between 10M and 4096G-1" on Oracle DB startup

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, connectivity

My Oracle DB 12c instance was not starting up. While connected as an idle instance ( / as sysdba ) and executing `startup;` command, I was getting an error:

> ORA-00093: pga_aggregate_target must be between 10M and 4096G-1

Comment: Was it its first startup attempt? Did it fail all of a sudden? Did you change anything in the configuration? Have you had a look at [that setting](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams157.htm#REFRN10165)?

Answer (score 3):

Found an answer at : http://www.databaseskill.com/400704/

But the explanation is not very clear. To summarize :

1. This property 'pga_aggregate_target' is in a file called an spfile which is present at *'`C:\app\dbhome\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\database`'* for example.
2. I edited this value to one fitting the range which in my case I changed to `855638016`
3. Further you require a init file at the same path. If one is not present at the above path you can retrieve a file from *'`C:\app\dbhome\admin\orcl\pfile`'* and rename it to `initorcl.ora`
4. After doing the above steps connect to an idle instance by running `sqlplus / as sysdba` and try the `startup;` command

Answered my own question for future reference

Comment: Manually editing an spfile doesn't seem like a great idea; changing the values with `alter` commands, or creating a pfile from the spfile, editing that, and starting up from that pfile sound safer. Curious how you got the invalid value there in the first place though.

Comment: Your web link does not say to edit the spfile which normally results in further  errors.  It indicates to create a pfile from spfile and then edit that.

Comment: For Oracle 19c the path of the spfile is <ora_home>/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1/dbs/

Answer (score 1):

Oracle 12.2 onwards the value of 'PGA_Aggregate_Limit' has to be at the minimum twice the value of 'PGA_Aggregate_Target' in case the 'Memory_Target' has not been explicitly set.
Therefore, you can face this error even when you attempt to modify PGA_Aggregate_Limit (not just on startup).
If one is facing ORA-00093, one must first set/change the PGA_Aggregate_Target to half of the PGA_Aggregate_Limit and re-try changing PGA_Aggregate_Limit.

Comment: I am pretty sure that he does not know how to change it so you should add this to your answer.